# Saving a value in a class to be used later

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to c# so I'm not sure what to do here, I want to save a value from one class to another. It's hard to explain but this is what I got. https://pastebin.com/UU7vjuqK (I know it's pretty messy)

```
class hero {
    private int _armor = 0;
    public int armor
        {
        get { return _armor; }
            set
            {
                if (value <= 0)
                {
                _armor = 0;
                }
                else if (value >= 20)
                {
                _armor = 20;
                }
                else
                {
                _armor = value;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

So what I want is to increase the Hero armour by 5 as seen in the walking() method. I then want to add that 5 armour to my hero class and save the value and later do what I want with it. I hope this makes sense, because it sure dosen't for me

Comment: It is poor etiquette here on SO to link out to code, especially so much code with super annoying video ads playing. I suspect your question is more general than us having to know about your game. Do you just need to know how to persist data? Like database, file, cache etc?

Comment: As I said I'm pretty new (started for real yesterday), so I'm not sure what I'm looking for... Up until now I've only used HTML CSS and Jquery so this is something totally new for me

Comment: Do you mean you want to save the state of `armor` so that, for instance, if you rebooted  your machine it would come back to where you left off?

Comment: no just so I could reuse it somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you create a new instance of your class, you have a *new* instance.  Changes made to any other instance won't be present in the new one.

Consider an analogy... A car rolls off the factory production line.  As it comes out of the factory, you put a bag in the trunk.  Moments later, another identical car comes out of the factory.  It's completely identical to the first one in every way.  If you open the trunk of the second car, would you expect to find your bag there?

You have a few options:

1. Maintain the same instance of your object throughout the intended logic.  For any ongoing logical process this would generally make sense.  An object exists and should be passed around where it's needed.  You wouldn't expect to have to keep creating new instances of everything.
2. Persist the state (data) of your objects somewhere so that state can be re-loaded later.  This generally makes sense in systems where you don't want to maintain state in memory, such as web applications.  Or any system where you expect the application to terminate and you want to pick up where you left off next time it runs.

(Technically I suppose using `static` values would be a third option.  But that option doesn't appear to make much sense here.  You wouldn't have a single "armor" value for *all* "hero" objects.  Each would have its own.)

Which direction you want to take is up to you.  The simplest example of the first one is probably to just pass an object to a method.  Something like:

```
var myHero = new Hero();
myHero.Armor += 5;
SomeMethod(myHero);

// elsewhere...
void SomeMethod(Hero aHero)
{
    // here, "aHero" has an armor increased by 5
}
```

The second option above of course gets *slightly* more complicated, as you'd need to write code which would save and restore state.  This would be a good opportunity to start working with databases.  Frameworks such as Entity Framework make light work of that in code, once you get over the learning curve of understanding what a database is and how to set it all up.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this :)

Answer (score 0):

You've to create a instance of Hero outside the Walk method. Something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var hero = new Hero();

    hero.Walk();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Current Armo: {0}", hero.Armor));

    hero.Walk();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Current Armo: {0}", hero.Armor));
}

public class Hero
{
    public int Armor { get; set; }

    public void Walk()
    {
        this.Armor += 5;
    }
}
```

Code runing here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/5LDC0g

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try this as well :)

Answer (score 0):

so you should know that we have 3 kind of storing.

if the later can could be any time after closing the app or ... you should use a database (or to start learning i offer you [storing data in a text file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file))
Like this:

```
string file_name = "c:\\file.txt";

System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name, true);

objWriter.Write(armor);
```

here you can write your armor in a file and you can [read the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file) each time you need like this:

```
string armor= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.txt");
```

so you can use this two steps to your class when get; or set; armor value.

The other 2 ways to store data is caching for middle long or store it in a object of a your class (As David Answer) to use it till you didn't closed your app.

Comment: thanks wish I could put more than one as the correct answer :)